# Bug when calling ml.Preprocess on a feature_set consisting of a single ImageFeatureColumn

Tags: python, google-cloud-ml

I get the following error when I call `ml.Preprocess` on a `feature_set` that contains a single feature that is an `ml.features.ImageFeatureColumn`:

> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'producer'

I believe this is a bug, and that it happens as follows:

- `ml.Preprocess.apply` calls `AnalyzeData.apply`
- At `google.cloud.ml.features._analysis.py:108`, an `IdentityColumnAnalyzer` for the image column produces a metadata object that is a singleton list containing a dict
- This means that `analysis_list` becomes a singleton list containing this singleton list of a dict
- At `google.cloud.ml.features._analysis.py:114`, when `analysis_list` is piped into `beam.Flatten()`, the output is a list and not a PCollection.
- This output being a list causes problems later down the line

This bug can be demonstrated by running the following as a script: http://pastebin.com/ECMt0wDC

This happens only when `feature_set` contains a single feature. I think this is because when there's multiple features, `analysis_list` contains multiple objects, at least one of which is a PCollection, which leads to `beam.Flatten` correctly producing a PCollection. Furthermore, this happens only when that single feature is an `ImageFeatureColumn` because most, if not all, other feature types do not use `IdentityColumnAnalyzer`.

BTW, this is on version 0.1.7-alpha of `google.cloud.ml`.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed info, jwayne.  We're investigating and will get back to you.

Comment: Note that there is new functionality since the old alpha sdk. See my answer below for couple of pointers.

Answer (score 0):

Note that we have a more out-of-box capability for image classification (from the question, thats what it sounds like you are doing).

This is available in Cloud Datalab (https://cloud.google.com/datalab) and a sample notebook demonstrating this functionality is at https://github.com/googledatalab/notebooks/blob/master/samples/ML%20Toolbox/Image%20Classification/Flower/Local%20End%20to%20End.ipynb (these notebooks are automatically loaded into Datalab as documentation).

Hope that helps you in your use-case!